# Close dropdown menu on click or scroll outside the menu

Tags: menus

I am using Sydney theme on my WordPress webpage. But I found an issue that I want to fix. While I open the webpage on phone, the webpage is using the "hamburger" dropdown menu. The problem is that when I click the "hamburder" the dropdown menu opens. But they if I don't select anything from the menu and just scroll down the menu stay open. Are they any CSS code that can fix this? Thank anyone for your help =)

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to WordPress SE. Questions relating directly to CSS or JavaScript might be better directed towards StackOverflow.